# Can i append data direct to an array already stored in UserDefaults key

Tags: arrays, swift, append, store, userdefaults

I have myArray with 80k member Int64.

myArray stored by key "datakey" in UserDefaults.

**Can i append data direct to key: "datakey" for save time when i write into UserDefaults.**

Normanly i can do this by some steps:

1. Read array from UserDefaults "datakey"

   readArray = UserDefaults.standard.array(forKey: "datakey") as! [Int64]
2. append new member to readArray:

   readArray.append(newNumber)
3. Re-write data to "datakey":

   UserDefaults.standard.set(readArray, forKey: "datakey")

but as i said the array have more than 80k member, it take so long to complete write to UserDefaults

**==>>Can i append data direct to key: "datakey" for save time when i write into UserDefaults.**

Comment: I don't think you can. You should consider using a faster database for that, for example CoreData, UserDefaults are not meant for heavy usage.

Comment: Or save it to file(s) depending of what your use case is for this data.

Comment: I would save it as raw bytes straight to disk

Comment: Yes, thank you for all your recomend. I also think ralate to use coredata. Save to disk will take short time than save to file